# How can I read from MQTT with the Apache Beam Python SDK

Tags: apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I'm trying to read from an MQTT topic using the Apache Beam Python SDK v2.50.0 with multi-language support - [MQTT IO](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/v2.50.0/sdks/java/io/mqtt/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/mqtt/MqttIO.java) is available via the Java SDK, but not the Python SDK). [Here are the docs I'm following](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#1311-creating-cross-language-java-transforms).

```py
import argparse
import logging
from typing import Callable, NamedTuple, Optional

import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from apache_beam.transforms.external import JavaExternalTransform



def run(
    username: str,
    password: str,
    server_uri: str = 'mqtts:HOSTNAME:8883',
    topic: str = 'TOPIC_NAME',
    beam_options: Optional[PipelineOptions] = None,
) -> None:
    with beam.Pipeline(options=beam_options) as pipeline:
        MqttConfig = NamedTuple('MqttConfig', [('serverUri', str), ('topic', str), ('clientId', str), ('username', str), ('password', str)])
        
        mqtt_config = MqttConfig(serverUri=server_uri, topic=topic, clientId='random123', username=username, password=password)

        read_java_transform = JavaExternalTransform(
            'org.apache.beam.sdk.io.mqtt.MqttIO',
        ).read().withConnectionConfiguration(list(mqtt_config))

        data = (
            pipeline 
            | 'Read' >> read_java_transform
            | 'ToString' >> beam.Map(lambda x: x.decode('utf-8'))
            | 'Print' >> beam.Map(print)
        )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument(
        "--username", 
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        "--password",
    )
    parser.add_argument(
      '--server_uri',
      help='MQTT server URI',
      )
    parser.add_argument(
      '--topic',
      help='MQTT topic to subscribe to',
      )
    known_args, beam_args = parser.parse_known_args()

    beam_options = PipelineOptions(
        # save_main_session=True, 
        beam_args
    )

    run(
        **vars(known_args),
        beam_options=beam_options,
    )
```

When I run the file with `poetry run python3 main.py --runner DirectRunner --environment_type=DOCKER --username=USERNAME --password=API_KEY`, I get the following error:

```
RuntimeError: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find class org.apache.beam.sdk.io.mqtt.MqttIO
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.expansion.service.JavaClassLookupTransformProvider.getTransform(JavaClassLookupTransformProvider.java:131)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.expansion.service.ExpansionService$TransformProvider.apply(ExpansionService.java:402)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.expansion.service.ExpansionService.expand(ExpansionService.java:555)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.expansion.service.ExpansionService.expand(ExpansionService.java:639)
    at org.apache.beam.model.expansion.v1.ExpansionServiceGrpc$MethodHandlers.invoke(ExpansionServiceGrpc.java:306)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p54p0.io.grpc.stub.ServerCalls$UnaryServerCallHandler$UnaryServerCallListener.onHalfClose(ServerCalls.java:182)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p54p0.io.grpc.internal.ServerCallImpl$ServerStreamListenerImpl.halfClosed(ServerCallImpl.java:355)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p54p0.io.grpc.internal.ServerImpl$JumpToApplicationThreadServerStreamListener$1HalfClosed.runInContext(ServerImpl.java:867)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p54p0.io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p54p0.io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:133)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.beam.sdk.io.mqtt.MqttIO
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:527)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.expansion.service.JavaClassLookupTransformProvider.getTransform(JavaClassLookupTransformProvider.java:107)
    ... 12 more
```

The error appears after the expansion server appears to have started automatically. Here is the related stdout:

```
INFO:root:Missing pipeline option (runner). Executing pipeline using the default runner: DirectRunner.
/Users/daniel/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/good-data-app-rAL-Zgkg-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/transforms/external.py:676: BeamDeprecationWarning: options is deprecated since First stable release. References to <pipeline>.options will not be supported
  self._expansion_service, pipeline.options)
INFO:apache_beam.utils.subprocess_server:Using cached job server jar from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/beam/beam-sdks-java-expansion-service-app/2.50.0/beam-sdks-java-expansion-service-app-2.50.0.jar
INFO:root:Starting a JAR-based expansion service from JAR /Users/daniel/.apache_beam/cache/jars/beam-sdks-java-expansion-service-app-2.50.0.jar 
INFO:apache_beam.utils.subprocess_server:Starting service with ['java' '-jar' '/Users/daniel/.apache_beam/cache/jars/beam-sdks-java-expansion-service-app-2.50.0.jar' '61991' '--javaClassLookupAllowlistFile=*']
INFO:apache_beam.utils.subprocess_server:Starting expansion service at localhost:61991
INFO:apache_beam.utils.subprocess_server:Sep 24, 2023 7:10:25 AM org.apache.beam.sdk.expansion.service.ExpansionService loadRegisteredTransforms
INFO:apache_beam.utils.subprocess_server:INFO: Registering external transforms: [beam:external:java:generate_sequence:v1]
INFO:apache_beam.utils.subprocess_server:
INFO:apache_beam.utils.subprocess_server:Registered transforms:
INFO:apache_beam.utils.subprocess_server:   beam:external:java:generate_sequence:v1: org.apache.beam.sdk.expansion.service.ExpansionService$ExternalTransformRegistrarLoader$1@413d1baf
INFO:apache_beam.utils.subprocess_server:Sep 24, 2023 7:10:26 AM org.apache.beam.sdk.expansion.service.ExpansionService expand
INFO:apache_beam.utils.subprocess_server:INFO: Expanding 'Read/ExternalTransform(beam:expansion:payload:java_class_lookup:v1)' with URN 'beam:expansion:payload:java_class_lookup:v1'
INFO:apache_beam.utils.subprocess_server:Dependencies list: {}
```

I believe that the MqttIO class meets the following specifications:

> To be eligible for direct usage, the API of the Java transform has to meet the following requirements: 1. The Java transform can be constructed using an available public constructor or a public static method (a constructor method) in the same Java class. 2. The Java transform can be configured using one or more builder methods. Each builder method should be public and should return an instance of the Java transform.

I've double-checked that the fully qualified class name `'org.apache.beam.sdk.io.mqtt.MqttIO'` is correct.

What am I missing here?

Comment: If you use DirectRunner, did you run it like this https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python-multi-language-pipelines/#run-the-pipeline?

Comment: @XQHu I ran it with poetry `poetry run python3 main.py --username=USERNAME --password=API_KEY`. When I add the flags `--environment_type=DOCKER  --runner DirectRunner` I get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the *expansion service jar* used to startup the expansion service here (*beam-sdks-java-expansion-service-app-2.50.0.jar*) does not include the *org.apache.beam.sdk.io.mqtt.MqttIO* Java transform you are trying to use through Python.

Can you try starting a Java expansion service manually and make sure that *beam-sdks-java-io-mqtt* jar and other required dependencies are available in the classpath when you startup the expansion service ? It might be more convenient to build a shaded jar that includes the MQTT jar and its dependencies. For examples, see [here](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/io/expansion-service/build.gradle) for the Main class and dependencies we include for the IO expansion service jar build we use for Kafka. See [here](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python-multi-language-pipelines/#choose-an-expansion-service) for the command that you can use to start the expansion service. Once the expansion service is built, you can specify its address through the parameter [here](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/f35a4130ef35b534d93e2dfa9f88f22cf8cd1d27/sdks/python/apache_beam/transforms/external.py#L509).

Ideally Beam should provide a Python multi-lang wrapper to make this convenient for you. But this is not available yet.